# How do I link to a gif image using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have implemented endless scrolling to my website user account area and before more data is loaded when a user scrolls text is briefly displayed as you can see in the code here:

```
if ($('.pagination').length) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var url;
    url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
    if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
      $('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...");
       $.getScript(url);
    }
  });
  $(window).scroll();
};
```

I have an animated gif image I'd like to display instead and wondering how to go about doing this? Is it possible to link directly to the image?

What is the correct way to display an image instead of text?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the method from `text()` to `html()`, something like:

```
$('.pagination').html('<img src="loading.gif" width="30" height="30" alt="loading..." />');
```

You can use any form of HTML within the method, so you could wrap the image in a link or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.pagination').html($('<img src="yourimage.gif"/>');
```

OR

```
$('.pagination').html($('<img/>').attr('src','yourimage.gif'));
```

Comment: I don't know if the second one would work - the `html` method takes as argument a string... if you're already constructing an img element, why not use `append` instead of `html`?

Comment: Yea, it "works" but that’s just jQuery being "nice". It looks kinda awkward to create a jQuery instance and then just toss it away to innerHTML using an internal interpreter. It’s also not in the docs, so it might not work forever...

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there is a "correct" way, but considering your existing code this should be simple enough:

```
$('.pagination').html('<img src="spinner.gif">');
```

Another tempting option would be to add the spinner using some CSS:

```
.pagination.loading{background:url('spinner.gif') no-repeat}
```

And then toggle the class:

```
$('.pagination').addClass('loading');
```

But again, this all depends on your workflow and visual preference.